# Two or more loaded controllers with the same name "admin" are not working in HMVC in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

The structure looks like this:

```
modules
    admin
        controllers/
            admin.php
        models/
            admin_model.php
        views/
            admin/
                index.php
    categories/
        controllers/
            admin.php
            categories.php
        models/
            categories_model.php
        views/
            admin/
                index.php
                menu.php
            frontpage.php
    posts/
        controllers/
            admin.php
            posts.php
        models/
            posts_model.php
        views/
            admin/
                index.php
                menu.php
            frontpage.php
```

The admin controller looks like:

```
class Admin extends Backend_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('categories_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
             // index stuff
    }

    public function _menu()
    {
         $this->load->view('categories/admin/menu');
    }

}
```

And when I am calling it from another module view like this:

```
<?php echo Modules::run('categories/admin/_menu'); ?>
```

it doesn't work ;(

However this works:

```
<?php echo Modules::run('categories/categories'); ?>
```

So my problem is how to load the controller with a name **admin** and not the name as the module's name and the method "**menu**"

Any idea how could I make it work in CodeIgniter?

**EDIT:**

**I have found out that if I change my controller name from "admin" to something else e.g. "blablacontroller" it magically starts working.**

**I have already another module called "admin" so could this be a problem?**

Comment: Does it work if you do public menu() instead of _menu (which marks it private) ?

Comment: I have tried **menu** without the underscore, but it doesn;t load at all too. I guess HMVC has problem to load another controller. Any idea how to load it?

Comment: Any idea what how to fix this?

Comment: I have find out that using the name **admin** for my controller is causing the problem. However, I don't know why. So, if I change it to **blablacontroller** it start working. What could be the case that "admin" is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm right, you are using Modular Extensions - HMVC. So I've based my answer on the following script : https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/868e97533562e910d8263af22750985d57004baa/third_party/MX/Modules.php?at=default.

This will only work if you are using PHP 5.3 or above.

- Declare every Admin classes inside a namepsace (admin, categories, post) by adding ***namespace admin;*** before the class keywork.
- Create a child class of *third_party/MX/Modules.php* and extend the run and load methods. If extending is not possible, you'll have to replace the methods :/
- This is not the whole thing, but those simples string operations should be in the load method before the existing logic.
- A module should be run with the following syntax : ***Modules::run('categories\admin/_menu');***

  ```
  $module = 'categories\admin';
  if (strpos($module, '\\') !== false)
  {
      // Extract namespace
      $ns = explode('\\', $module);

      // Get the top level namespace to locate the controller
      $top_level_ns = reset($ns); //

      // Remove namespace from module
      $module = array_pop($ns);

      // Class location
      $path = APPPATH . $top_level_ns . '/controllers/' . $module;

      // It's better to extend the load_file method
      include_once $path . EXT;

      // Full class name with namespace, we use explode on $module in case of sub folders
      $controller = '\\' . implode('\\', $ns) . '\\' . ucfirst(end(explode('/', $module))) . CI::$APP->config->item('controller_suffix');

      // create and register the new controller
      $alias = strtolower($controller);
      self::$registry[$alias] = new $controller($params);

      var_dump('Full class name: ' . $controller, 'Class path: ' . $path);
  }
  ```

Comment: Here is the sample running : [http://codepad.org/Civc374H](http://codepad.org/Civc374H).

Answer (score 3):

In PHP you can only have a single class declared with a name. Eg. you can only have a single Admin class unless the classes are in different namespaces. What might be happening is:

`admin/controllers/admin.php` is declared then later in your scripts execution `categories/controllers/admin.php` is attempted to be declared and throws an error as `admin/controllers/admin.php` already exists and which `Admin` class should it use if some code somewhere says `new Admin()`.

If both classes are needed then one will need to renamed, or the code to be restructured so that only one of them is declared in a single execution cycle. I am not too sure if the HMVC stuff your using will allow namespaces, but you can look at extending it that way. If not maybe rename both admin classes to something a bit more specific.